# Getting verify.dll not found error message while opening Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

My Eclipse IDE(INDIGO) was working perfectly till last week. But Now, while I try to open my eclipse am getting "This application has failed to start because verify.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem." I googled about this error and I did some tries but it doesn't works. :(

[image]

Tries which I made:

1. downloaded verify.dll and placed in plugins folder under eclipse root directory.
2. downloaded verify.dll and placed in windows32 folder.
3. Downloaded different Eclipse versions and getting same error messages for those versions also.

Pls... help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem as follows:

Searched on my C:\ drive for "verify.dll".

Found it in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin

In my PATH environment variable, I had a path to C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin, which doesn't contain a verify.dll file.

Changed the path to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin in the PATH variable, and re-started Eclipse successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Well, have you tried to uninstall, and re-install it completely? This should help, as stated in the dialog.

Comment: I have not using eclipse as installed in my machine. I am just using it as a plug and play. I have just opening it by executing eclipse.exe file.

Comment: Download the zipped version.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the path of Java (I had the problem with Juno 4.2) to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin (Windows 8 OS).

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy a valid `verify.dll` here:
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_??\jre\bin`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I uninstalled java and eclipse. 
Then I reinstalled them by first installing java than eclipse as I read that java must be installed before eclipse and it fixed it for me.